# Detect markers in macro arguments

Tags: fonts, macros, formatting

I'd like to find a way to define a command which would work like this

```
\mycommand{This +is+ a +simple example+.}
```

and give

> This **is** a **simple example**.

i.e a command which looks for words surrounded by a particular symbol (here a `+`) and changes the formatting (here in **bold**) of these words.

Also, is there any references about "advanced" macros in TeX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is easy:

```
\def\mycommand{\begingroup\setupplus\mycommandaux}
\def\setupplus{%
  \catcode`+=\active
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`+\lowercase{\endgroup\def~##1~}{\textbf{##1}}%
}
\newcommand\mycommandaux[1]{#1\endgroup}
```

You open a group and in this group you set up `+` to be active; its action is to gather everything up to the next `+` and to print it in boldface. The important thing is to gather the argument after the setup has been performed. So the action is split into two and `\mycommandaux` gathers the argument, so that TeX can process it, and closes the group started by `\mycommand`.

Don't use such shortcuts; they'll bite you, some day or the other.

Caution: this `\mycommand` cannot be used in the argument of another command. If you need it there, then a slightly more complicated strategy is needed:

```
\protected\def\mycommand{\begingroup\setupplus\mycommandaux}
\def\setupplus{%
  \catcode`+=\active
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`+\lowercase{\endgroup\def~##1~}{\textbf{##1}}%
}
\newcommand\mycommandaux[1]{\scantokens{#1\noexpand}\endgroup}
```